# C# Unexpected output from a singleton pattern class that is creating different instances at run time

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, singleton

I am learning design patterns. I created a singleton Logger class that should return an new instance of logger only if it is null, and return the same instance every time otherwise. But implementing the class is resulting in creating a new instance everytime.

```
public class Logger
{
    private Logger()
    {

    }

    private static Logger instance;

    public static Logger Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance == null ? new Logger() : instance;
        }
    }
}

static void Main ()
{
    Logger log1 = Logger.Instance;
    Logger log2 = Logger.Instance;

    Console.WriteLine(log1.GetHashCode());
    Console.WriteLine(log2.GetHashCode());
}
```

The resulting hashcode is supposed to be the same on both lines but its not. Why is that?

Comment: You don't actually _set_ `instance`.

Comment: I know and I don't need to at this point. I only need to make sure that only one instance of logger is created at run time

Comment: @nour: How do you expect to do that without remembering at all whether or not you've already created an instance? How do you expect to "return the same instance every time otherwise" if you don't remember the instance you've created? What's the point of comparing `instance` with `null`, when it's *always* going to be null? Your `Instance` property is equivalent to `public static Logger Instance => new Logger();`

Comment: _"I know and I don't need to at this point."_ - Yes you do. How do you expect to return the _same_ instance on the next call?

Comment: _"Unexpected output from a singleton pattern class that `is creating different instances` at run time....I know and `I don't need to [set instance]` at this point..."_ - I fail to understand your logic

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Logger Instance
{
    get
    {
        return instance == null ? new Logger() : instance; // You do not _set_ 'instance' !
    }
}
```

So, this should be more like

```
public static Logger Instance
{
    get
    {
        if( instance is null ) instance = new Logger();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Mind that **this is not threadsafe**.

About the correct and safe implementation of Singletons, there are many articles written by people that can do that way better than I ever could. I suggest you explore that a little.

Comment: Or the newer short version: `instance ??= new Logger();`

Comment: @Klamsi I intentionally chose the explicit version. But yes, that would be possible. Doesn't make it threadsafe, though.

Comment: @Klamsi yes true but please note, a good answer should try to resemble the OP's code as much as possible otherwise they might not understand 1) _where the mistake was made_ 2) _the new code_ if it differs too much from the original 3) _newly introduced sugar-syntax,_ which whilst may save typing & impact little to the compiler, is generally less apparent in initial meaning

Comment: ^^ Basically. When I see OP has 11 rep, I won't be using superduper special syntax sugar but clear, readable and "vanilla" expressions. (Except it is that what the question is about.)

Comment: @Fildor agreed.  The amount of times I've seen code (`foreach` or button click events) in questions needlessly re-written with disproportionate answers involving say _LINQ-chained-methods_ or _Rx_ boggles the mind lol

Answer (score 1):

you must initialize the "instance" field with the new logger instance before returning it or it will always be null.

```
if (instance == null)
{
    instance = new Logger();
}
return instance;
```

you can also use a single expression

`return instance == null ? (instance = new Logger()) : instance;`

Note: in a multi-thread environment you need to use a lock or other synchronizations

Comment: Take the `{ }` away and your answer is essentially the same as [Fildor's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68266096/585968)